# Find directory name and file size in Linux

Tags: find, du

I have various folders used for product feeds across my server named 'empro'. Sometimes these folders fill up so I find them all on the server using:

```
find /var/www/vhosts -type d -name 'empro'
```

This will correctly give me the full list of the directories I'm looking for and then I'll manually use:

```
du -h
```

Is there a way I can run the find command as well as outputting the directory size in human-readable format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
find /var/www/vhosts -type d -name 'empro' | xargs du -sh
```

It's the same `find` sentence, and then through `xargs` you make a `du -sh` of each directory found.

Comment: `find` and `xargs` work nicely together with the `-print0` and `-0` options, to handle filenames with blanks, newlines, crazy characters in them. And the syntax has less `{}` & `\;` characters so less excaping/quoting

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
find /var/www/vhosts -type d -name 'empro' -exec du -h {} \;
```

If you want to keep the information only for particular directory you can use -s key:

```
find /var/www/vhosts -type d -name 'empro' -exec du -sh {} \;
```